# Navigation based popover?

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I would like to make a navigation based popover master pane kinda like the one in ipad mail app.I already have the data in a uitable view in the popover, how would i put each of them nd their own category in a navigation based popover.

Thanks,

Elvin

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to create a UINavigation controller, which loads your table as the content of the navigation controller. The popovercontroller will load you UINavigation controller.

If you create a split view-based you can see how its implemented there.

Answer (score 0):

@Paul Peelen gave you the answer.

To do it in storyboard simply select your table view then go in

```
Menu -> Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller
```

that will do the trick